# Neo4j sum subresults in a query

Tags: neo4j, subquery

I have a node person that has 3 different relationship with other nodes. Every relationship has a number associated that represents how important is this relationship in the graph.

This is the part of the schema that i am focuesd now (For the sake of readability the queries below are written in english. *lavora_in* is **works_in**, *vive_con* is **lives_with** and *conosce* is **knows**)

[image]

So, for every person i count the number of times it has a certain relationship and i multiply it by a certain factor:

```
match (p:Person) - [v:lives_with] - (p1:Person)
return p.id, (count(*)*10) as cnt
```

```
match (p:Person) - [v:works_in] - (d:Division)
return p.id, (count(*)*6) as cnt
```

```
match (p:Person) - [v:knows] - (p1:Person)
return p.id, (count(*)*4) as cnt
```

So at the end i'll obtain 3 different values for each person and i'd like to sum them. What i thought to do is to create these 3 functions and then sum their result based on the person's id in a fourth one

```
match (p:Person)
set p.overallSum = // query1 + query2 + query3
return p.id, p.overallSum
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in a single query, and simplify by working with relationship degrees (which we can know from the node itself) instead of expanding out and using count() aggregations. Best performance is when we don't need to know anything about the node at the other end (otherwise it must expand and filter on the other node), and your graph structure suggests that these relationships only connect nodes of these specific types and no others.

Here's how you do this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
RETURN p.id, size((p)-[:lives_with]-()) * 10 + 
             size((p)-[:works_in]-()) * 6 + 
             size((p)-[:knows]-()) * 4 as overallSum
```